# Reposition logo on phones with media query

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries, responsive

I am having some trouble with Bootstrap's media queries.
Currently, I have a fixed-top navbar with the logo centered above the links, like this:

[image]

When the menu collapses, the logo is pushed below, like this:

[image]

I want the logo to be centered vertically on smaller screens too, so I
created a media query to adjust margin-top, but it's not working.

Here's the code:

```css
body {
  padding-top: 40px;
  font-family: Consolas, monaco, monospace;
  color: #303030;
  padding-right: 80px;
  padding-left: 80px;
}


/* Add a dark background color with a little bit see-through */

.navbar {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: #303030;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  opacity: .9;
}

.navbar-nav {
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar-nav>li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  padding-top: 70px;
}

.navbar-fixed-top {
  position: fixed !important;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .navbar-brand {
    margin-top: -50px;
  }
}

.navbar-brand {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -100px !important;
  margin-top: -15px !important;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 30px
}

.navbar-toggle {
  z-index: 3;
}

.navbar-center {}


/* Add a gray color to all navbar links */

.navbar li a,
.navbar .navbar-brand {
  color: #beb5ac !important;
}


/* On hover, the links will turn white */

.navbar-nav li a:hover {
  color: #ded8d2 !important;
  transition: color 1s ease;
}


/* The active link */

.navbar-nav li.active a {
  color: #fff !important;
  background-color: #29292c !important;
}


/* Remove border color from the collapsible button */

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" media="screen">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="teste3.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="flexbox-footer.css">
</head>

<body class="Site">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header navbar-header-center">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
        <a class="navbar-center navbar-brand" href="./teste3.html">
          <img src="https://s22.postimg.org/stryqb4xd/logo.png" style="max-width:180px;"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="index"><a href="teste3.html">INÍCIO</a></li>
          <li class="sobre"><a href="teste3_about.html">SOBRE</a></li>
          <li class="ilustracao"><a href="teste3.html#ilustracao">ILUSTRAÇÃO</a></li>
          <li class="design"><a href="teste3.html#design">DESIGN GRÁFICO</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <script type='text/javascript' src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.mousewheel.pack.js?v=3.1.3"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scroll.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Tried several things but couldn't get this to work. Probably something silly. Thank you!

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/resch/5knzdsL0/

Comment: it would be of great help if we could actually see the logo in the snippet

Comment: Try to put `<a class="navbar-center navbar-brand" href="./teste3.html">
          <img src="logo.png" style="max-width:180px;" alt=""></a>` above `<div class="navbar-header navbar-header-center">`

Comment: @SergeInácio Thanks! Did it, still the same

Comment: I can't recreate your issue using your markup. Works fine for me although I'm missing fancybox.js and flexbox-footer.css. Probably unrelated but you have a leading slash on your fancybox-thumbs link as well. Can you post a minimum snippet that demonstrates the issue in question without the rest of the gubbins.

Comment: @WilliamRobinson sorry, edited the question with a fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add **!important** to your padding-top, since class already exits and it has higher priority than yours.

```
.navbar-brand {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -100px !important;
  margin-top: -15px !important;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 30px !important;
}
```

**EDIT:**

```css
body {
  padding-top: 40px;
  font-family: Consolas, monaco, monospace;
  color: #303030;
  padding-right: 80px;
  padding-left: 80px;
}


/* Add a dark background color with a little bit see-through */

.navbar {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: #303030;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  opacity: .9;
}

.navbar-nav {
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar-nav>li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  padding-top: 70px;
}

.navbar-fixed-top {
  position: fixed !important;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .navbar-brand {
    margin-top: -50px;
  }
}

.navbar-brand {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -100px !important;
  margin-top: -15px !important;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 30px !important;
}

.navbar-toggle {
  z-index: 3;
}

.navbar-center {}


/* Add a gray color to all navbar links */

.navbar li a,
.navbar .navbar-brand {
  color: #beb5ac !important;
}


/* On hover, the links will turn white */

.navbar-nav li a:hover {
  color: #ded8d2 !important;
  transition: color 1s ease;
}


/* The active link */

.navbar-nav li.active a {
  color: #fff !important;
  background-color: #29292c !important;
}


/* Remove border color from the collapsible button */

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" media="screen">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="teste3.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="flexbox-footer.css">
</head>

<body class="Site">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header navbar-header-center">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
        <a class="navbar-center navbar-brand" href="./teste3.html">
          <img src="logo.png" style="max-width:180px;"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="index"><a href="teste3.html">INÍCIO</a></li>
          <li class="sobre"><a href="teste3_about.html">SOBRE</a></li>
          <li class="ilustracao"><a href="teste3.html#ilustracao">ILUSTRAÇÃO</a></li>
          <li class="design"><a href="teste3.html#design">DESIGN GRÁFICO</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <script type='text/javascript' src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.mousewheel.pack.js?v=3.1.3"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scroll.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**EDIT 2:**

Set padding-top to 18px, working example can be found on the link provided in the comments section.

```
.navbar-brand {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -100px !important;
  margin-top: -15px !important;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 18px !important;
}
```

**EIDT 3:**

Notice two changes, `max-width` is set to 780px to include all mobile devices, and `paddign-top` is added.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 780px) {
  .navbar-brand {
    margin-top: -50px;
    padding-top: 18px !important;
  }
}
```

`padding-top` in class below is back to 30px;

```
.navbar-brand {
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -100px !important;
      margin-top: -15px !important;
      display: block;
      padding-top: 30px !important;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Did it, no luck.

Comment: Can you please put your code to jsFiddle or some other online tool.

Comment: But you altered the desktop version padding as well. I need it with padding-top 30px on desktop. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Thanks! Had to change the values a little but it worked!

Comment: You can assign an id to the`<nav>` div as well, then you can add your own styles to it instead of needing to use `!important`. The id will take precedence.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move your media query to the bottom of your style sheet so it takes priority and change it from margin to padding like so

```
@media screen and (max-width: 780px) {
  .navbar-brand {
     padding-top: 15px !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, ment to say you need to change max-width from 480 to 780. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your element is in position absolute, try to give it a top value

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .navbar-brand {
    top:0px
  }
}
```

Comment: Try it along with "padding-top: 0;" ?